# Cannot add parameter to Excel Services

Tags: excel, excel-services, connected-web-parts, excel-web-access-webpart

In the `Browser View Options` `Parameters` in Excel, why can't we select a desired named field when we click `Add`?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason was that:

- Formulas aren't supported in the named value
- Data validation isn't supported in the named value

See more info here: https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Change-workbook-parameters-in-Excel-Services-5e6f3c25-4d58-4040-931a-c769dddd62df

[image]